# Trying to get a count of each word in a MongoDB field is this a job for MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mapreduce

I've got a collection with a bunch of body posts in it.  For example:

```
posts = { { id: 0, body: "foo bar baz", otherstuff: {...} },
          { id: 1, body: "baz bar oof", otherstuff: {...} },
          { id: 2, body: "baz foo oof", otherstuff: {...} }
        };
```

I'd like to figure out how to loop through each document in the collection and carry a count of each word in each post body.

```
post_word_frequency = { { foo: 2 },
                        { bar: 2 },
                        { baz: 3 },
                        { oof: 2 },
                      };
```

I've never used MapReduce and I'm still really fresh to mongo, but I'm looking at the documentation on http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/

```
map = function() {
    words = this.body.split(' ');
    for (i in words) {
       emit({ words[i] }, {count: 1});   
    }
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
     var count = 0;
     values.forEach(function(v) {
          count += v['count'];
     });
     return {count: count};
};

db.posts.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: post_word_frequency});
```

As a bit of an added difficulty, I'm doing it in node.js (with node-mongo-native, though am willing to switch to do the reduce query if there's an easier way).

```
    var db = new Db('mydb', new Server('localhost', 27017, {}), {native_parser:false});
    db.open(function(err, db){
            db.collection('posts', function(err, col) {
                db.col.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: post_word_frequency});
            });
    });
```

So far, I'm having difficulty in that node's telling me `ReferenceError: post_word_frequency is not defined` (I tried creating it in the shell, but that still didn't help).

So has anyone done a mapreduce with node.js? Is this the wrong use for map reduce? maybe another way to do it? (perhaps just loop and upsert into another collection?)

Thanks for any feedback and advice!  :)

**EDIT** Ryanos below was correct (thanks!) one thing that's missing from my MongoDB based solution was finding the collection and converting it to an array.

```
 db.open(function(err, db){
    db.collection('posts', function(err, col) {
            col.find({}).toArray(function(err, posts){    // this line creates the 'posts' array as needed by the MAPreduce functions.
                    var words= _.flatten(_.map(posts, function(val) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a bug with `{out: post_word_frequency}` maybe you want `{out: "post_word_frequency"}` but it should work without this `out` variable.

Using [`underscore`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) it can be simply done.

```
/*
  [{"word": "foo", "count": 1}, ...]
*/
var words = _.flatten(_.map(posts, function(val) {
    return _.map(val.body.split(" "), function(val) {
        return {"word": val, "count": 1};
    });
}));

/*
  {
    "foo": n, ...
  }
*/
var count = _.reduce(words, function(memo, val) {
    if (_.isNaN(++memo[val.word])) {
        memo[val.word] = 1;
    }
    return memo;
}, {});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/NcTrb/6/)

[`_.reduce`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reduce), [`_.map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map), [`_.isNaN`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isNaN), [`_.flatten`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#flatten)

Comment: this is awesome!  thanks.  I'll check the answer when I get home from work and let you know if it goes. I've never seen underscore before, can that be loaded in node.js ?

Comment: @AlexC just `npm install underscore` && `var _ = require("underscore");`

Comment: great! it's definitely working in your example - i'm still trying to collect all the dots on the mongo bit, but I'm sure that'll come soon.  Thanks a tonne! :)